# Spark application fails due to "FileSystem closed" exception

Tags: apache-spark

My spark application failed due to "FileSystem closed" exception. A typical  stacktrace is attached at the end. I did some research and this indicates executor got shutdown (see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24038908/spark-fails-on-big-shuffle-jobs-with-java-io-ioexception-filesystem-closed)).

This could happen due to large shuffle or out-of-memory exceptions, but I couldn't find any of those in the yarn log.

My question is:

1. if those exception happened, where would I find them if not in the yarn logs?
2. if those exceptions never happen, what should I do other than investigating the yarn log?

Thanks!

Here is a snippet of yarn log:

```
2017-08-21 01:55:10,668 ERROR  org.apache.spark.scheduler.LiveListenerBus: Listener EventLoggingListener threw an exception
java.io.IOException: Filesystem closed
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient.checkOpen(DFSClient.java:837)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSOutputStream.flushOrSync(DFSOutputStream.java:2170)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSOutputStream.hflush(DFSOutputStream.java:2116)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FSDataOutputStream.hflush(FSDataOutputStream.java:130)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor11.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at com.pepperdata.common.reflect.b.b(SourceFile:149)
        at com.pepperdata.common.reflect.b.c(SourceFile:205)
        at com.pepperdata.supervisor.agent.resource.T.b(SourceFile:102)
        at com.pepperdata.supervisor.agent.resource.I.hflush(SourceFile:61)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.EventLoggingListener$$anonfun$logEvent$3.apply(EventLoggingListener.scala:140)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.EventLoggingListener$$anonfun$logEvent$3.apply(EventLoggingListener.scala:140)
        at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:236)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.EventLoggingListener.logEvent(EventLoggingListener.scala:140)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.EventLoggingListener.onJobStart(EventLoggingListener.scala:163)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.SparkListenerBus$class.doPostEvent(SparkListenerBus.scala:37)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.LiveListenerBus.doPostEvent(LiveListenerBus.scala:36)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.LiveListenerBus.doPostEvent(LiveListenerBus.scala:36)
        at org.apache.spark.util.ListenerBus$class.postToAll(ListenerBus.scala:63)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.LiveListenerBus.postToAll(LiveListenerBus.scala:36)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.LiveListenerBus$$anon$1$$anonfun$run$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply$mcV$sp(LiveListenerBus.scala:94)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.LiveListenerBus$$anon$1$$anonfun$run$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply(LiveListenerBus.scala:79)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.LiveListenerBus$$anon$1$$anonfun$run$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply(LiveListenerBus.scala:79)
        at scala.util.DynamicVariable.withValue(DynamicVariable.scala:57)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.LiveListenerBus$$anon$1$$anonfun$run$1.apply$mcV$sp(LiveListenerBus.scala:78)
        at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryOrStopSparkContext(Utils.scala:1245)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.LiveListenerBus$$anon$1.run(LiveListenerBus.scala:77)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Spark fails on big shuffle jobs with java.io.IOException: Filesystem closed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24038908/spark-fails-on-big-shuffle-jobs-with-java-io-ioexception-filesystem-closed)

Answer (score 1):

Well I just found out the cause of the problem is the same FileSystem accidentally gets closed() multiple times. Not calling close() makes the exception disappear.